# wsdl2objc NSString error

Tags: objective-c, wsdl, nsstring, subclass

In mi wsdl2objc generated code I have:

```
@interface tns6_EntityType : NSString  {

/* elements */
/* attributes */
    NSNumber * id_;
}
```

However, when I get an element of this type, I get the following error:

> 2011-03-26 21:23:02.428 Pez[47129:a0f] Exception detected while handling key input.
>
> 2011-03-26 21:23:02.428 Pez[47129:a0f] *** -length only defined for abstract class.  Define -[tns6_EntityType length]!

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ilke you need to add your own implementation for `-length` on the class `tns6_EntityType`. Remember that in Objective-C, NSString is the abstract parent of a *[class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html)*, and so subclassing it directly can sometimes have strange effects. If you continue to get errors like this, just read through the message and follow its directions.

Comment: Can you post your implementation (in your original question) for `[tns6_EntityType length]`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I modified the wsdl to have one NSString and one NSNumber. My implementation was return [super length], but it didn't work.

Comment: That won't work for the same reason - if you're subclassing NSString directly, you likely won't have `[super length]` to fall back on, since NSString isn't a concrete string class. Try returning your member string's length instead (e.g. `return [str_ length]` if your member string is called `str_`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when generated wsdl code to objC.

You can find my solution for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21331422/1891772.

In my example I used ARC. As I know wsdl2objc doesn't support ARC so you need change it my example:

1. Change in "stringHolder" property "strong" to "retain"
2. add "autorelease" to code line where property "stringHolder" initialized
3. add "self.stringHolder = nil" in dealloc method