# Using a NSString subclass in UILabel et.al

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, class-cluster

I need to encode additional data to a `NSString` (Long story, please don't ask why...)

I've subclassed `NSString` using the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895012/subclassing-nsstring):

When I assign one of these subclasses as a `UILabel's` text I would expect to get it back when asking the labels text. But this isn't the case. (I get an NSString cluster instance instead)

```
MyString *string = [[MyString alloc] initWithString:@"Some string"];
UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
l.text = string;
NSString *t = l.text;  // not getting the "MyString" object
```

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I think sub-classing is a no-no.  Did you explore categories?  Anyway I won't ask why you subclassed (not interested/you said not to), but I reckon you don't need to.

Comment: the UILabel text property is an NSString and , I think, that's the reason why you're not getting 'MyString' object. Maybe you'll need to subclass UILabel as well and setting the text property as 'MyString'.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text

Comment: subclassing `NSString` sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @enzo That doesn't make sense.  Even if the pointer to a class instance is to the base class, the sub-class still exists.  It's the copying that is the issue, as stated by Wain.

Comment: I agree that subclassing is bad - But swizzling is bad too. And when you swizzle UILabel:setText: sometimes you have no choice but to subclass NSString

Comment: @trojanfoe you're right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The label copies the string:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text
```

so you at least need to implement copy to return your subclass type and copy your other data.

(not that subclassing is the best idea)

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass NSString, you are braver than I would ever be, and you are totally on your own. NSString is a class cluster. You have basically not a chance in hell to subclass it and get it to work. It starts with the initialisation where [super init] which would be the NSString init method might return any kind of object.

Comment: According to the documentation it is possible. At the end of the day I am using the underlying NSString foundation. And yes, I am brave :)

Comment: ```It is possible to subclass NSString (and NSMutableString), but doing so requires providing storage facilities for the string (which is not inherited by subclasses) and implementing two primitive methods.```